# Commutativity relation on forms

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Working through Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* on page 79, is this a typo?

> $$
> \omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{kl} \, \eta \wedge \omega
> $$

Working through the identity I'm getting instead:
$$
\omega \wedge \eta = (-1)^{k+l} \, \eta \wedge \omega
$$

If I'm wrong, can somebody show why?

Comment: No, it's correct. You have to move each $dx_i$ by $l$ spaces, and you have $k$ of them to move. Therefore $kl$ swaps of adjacent terms.

Comment: I'm counting a transposition of K+L elements in switching

Comment: Try some small examples to get a feel for the length (minimum number of transpositions) of the permutation.

Comment: I just realized I had the wrong definition of sgn!  reconsidered counting transpositions and we're good.  All good to remove question if it overlaps with another sorry.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice way to see that a permutation of the form
$$
\binom{\,\color{blue}{1\,\ldots\,k}\;\color{green}{1\,\ldots\,l}\,}
{\,\color{green}{1\,\ldots\,l}\;\color{blue}{1\,\ldots\,k}\,}
$$
has length $kl$. Picture two highways running in parallel, one with $k$ lanes and the other with $l$ lanes. Now picture the roadway with $k$ lanes rising up and passing over to the other side of the roadway with $l$ lanes. Each of the $k$ lanes of one road must cross each of the $l$ lanes of the other *and there are no other crossings*. Counting these yields $kl$.

If you don't like highways, picture a braid with $k + l$ strands, where each of the $k$ strands must cross each of the $l$ other strands *and there are no other crossings*. Counting these crossings gives the *length* of the permutation (this number is minimal in this case), and reducing to parity gives the *sign* (doesn't depend on the crossings being minimal).

---

For example, with $k=3$ and $l=4$, we get $3 \cdot 4 = 12$ crossings, which is even, so the forms would commute without a sign. Here's a picture, where you can easily count the crossings.

[image: Permutation diagram on 3+4 strands.]